# Animate using margin-right

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, margin

Simple to-do for learning..... but its not working for me.

Task is simple, I am trying to rotate a box in square layout(Path : `go right -> down -> left -> up`)....**but its not animating after it moves `down`** (*doesn't go `left` or `up` after it*) this is the code :

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('.box').animate({
        "height": "40px",
            "width": "40px"
    }, 500, function () {
        $('.box').animate({
            "margin-left": "200px",  //go right
        }, 1500, function () {
            $('.box').animate({
                "margin-top": "200px", //go down
            }, 1500, function () {
                $('.box').animate({ // <===problem starts here
                    "margin-right": "200px" //go left
                    //"marginRight": "200px"
                }, 1500, function () {
                    $('.box').animate({
                        "margin-bottom": "200px" //go up
                    }, 1500, function () {
                        $('.box').css("background", "black")
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Is there any proper way to mix `margin`s while animating? Please advise...

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/p9xv7xv3/4/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('.box').animate({
        "height": "40px",
            "width": "40px"
    }, 500, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            "margin-left": "200px",  //go right
        }, 1500, function () {
            $(this).animate({
                "margin-top": "200px", //go down
            }, 1500, function () {
                $(this).animate({ // <===problem starts here
                    "margin-left": "-=200px" //go left
                    //"marginRight": "200px"
                }, 1500, function () {
                    $(this).animate({
                        "margin-top": "-=200px" //go up
                    }, 1500, function () {
                        $(this).css("background", "black")
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p9xv7xv3/5/)

Answer (score 2):

when you animate a item with one property the to change its behavior use that property it will easy like below

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('.box').animate({
        "height": "40px",
            "width": "40px"
    }, 500, function () {
        $('.box').animate({
            "margin-left": "200px",  //go right
        }, 1500, function () {
            $('.box').animate({
                "margin-top": "200px", //go down
            }, 1500, function () {
                $('.box').animate({ // <===problem starts here
                    "margin-left": "0px" //go left
                    //"marginRight": "200px"
                }, 1500, function () {
                    $('.box').animate({
                        "margin-top": "0px" //go up
                    }, 1500, function () {
                        $('.box').css("background", "black")
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9xv7xv3/6/)**

and as per your logic you need to add `-=` sign by which it come its previous value

like
 200

-200

gap is = 400

so use
-=200
now gap is 200 and its your need

like as **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p9xv7xv3/8/)**

Comment: ooo goodness.....super dumb from my part...thank god i dint changed my name from `Noob` :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to push the `div` from both sides, so it never goes left. What you need is to set `margin-left: 0px` to go left and `margin-top: 0px` to go up.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9xv7xv3/7/)

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('.box').animate({
        "height": "40px",
            "width": "40px"
    }, 500, function () {
        $('.box').animate({
            "margin-left": "200px",  //go right
        }, 1500, function () {
            $('.box').animate({
                "margin-top": "200px", //go down
            }, 1500, function () {
                $('.box').animate({ // <===problem starts here
                    "margin-left": "0px" //go left
                    //"marginRight": "200px"
                }, 1500, function () {
                    $('.box').animate({
                        "margin-top": "0px" //go up
                    }, 1500, function () {
                        $('.box').css("background", "black")
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```